# how to change the printer using c#

Tags: c#, printing

I have created a application to print documents with preview dialog.When i run my application it will print the document with default printer. Now i want to give option to the user to change the printer while printing using c# can someone please help me

thanks

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Post some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Just by googling the title of the question i got 3 working samples.

Comment: @Trickery the question is not off-topic, although it IS incomplete. Why change the default printer? Printing to a *specific* printer makes sense. So does letting the user select a printer and store the selection. .NET also provides a printer settings dialog. Is it not enough?

Comment: This is not supported in the preview.  For a good reason, the exact way the preview looks depends a lot of the specific printer.  You must do this the other way around, select the printer first and *then* generate the preview for it.  Easy to do with the PrintDialog class.

Comment: Yoav: please share your code. I have update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the below link, it might be useful.

http://caioproiete.net/en/programatically-change-the-default-printer-on-windows-usin-csharp/

Comment: In my code i want to list the printers available and let the users to select the printer. Can u pls share some code.

Comment: Link is not working